# Looking for dataset of pharmacy Locations in Chicago area

Tags: data-request, geospatial, data.gov, medical, uses-of-open-data

I'm looking for a dataset of pharmacy Locations in Chicago area. The city of Chicago said they do not have this dataset, I'm wondering where I can find it.

Comment: I would assume that pharmacists would have to be licensed in some way ... which means that there's a licensing board out there that would know the locations.

Answer (score 3):

The NPPES (npi) database released by CMS every month is one place to look. They have a record for everyone that has been issued an NPI number, which are needed to invoice and bill medicare and medicaid. Physicians, nurses, dialysis centers, hospitals and pharmacies all can be found in the data

There are many sites that allow an easy search of the dataset - here is 1 example searching "Pharmacy" in entity name, and state "IL"
[EXAMPLE: NPI Search for Pharmacy in IL](https://npidb.org/npi-lookup/?npi=&fname=&lname=&search=pharmacy&state=il&org=#main)

The full dataset can be downloaded
[NPPES Monthly Dissemination](https://www.cms.gov/Regulations-and-Guidance/HIPAA-Administrative-Simplification/NationalProvIdentStand/DataDissemination.html)

And they also now have an API that you can program an application to tap into the real-time latest version - npiregistry.cms.hhs.gov/registry/help-api

Answer (score 1):

socrata has two datasets on their open data portal, one for area code 606, the other is for the entire city (I am assuming):
https://opendata.socrata.com/Business/Pharmacies-In-Chicago-606xx-area-code/82dx-8n5s
https://opendata.socrata.com/Business/Pharmacies-in-Chicago/ytw2-tyid